# Is it possible to loop through a JSON file using shell to call to an API?

Tags: python, bash, shell

Wondering if it is possible to take a json file such as:

```
[
 {
   "firstName": "John",
   "lastName": "Doe",
   "dob": "1900-01-01",
   "zipCode": "12345",
   "subscriberId": "123456789",
   "policyNumber": "12345"
 },
 {
  "firstName": "Jane",
   "lastName": "Doe",
   "dob": "1900-01-01",
   "zipCode": "54321",
   "subscriberId": "987654321",
   "policyNumber": "54321"
 }
]
```

& looping over that data to call to the API.

The shell script that I'm using to make one call to the API looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Rally Forwarder Keys
clientkey=test
apikey=test
#SET apikey=test
# Public URL
url="test"

curl -v -X POST -d '{"firstName":"test","lastName":"test","dob":"1900-01-01","zipCode":"12345","subscriberId":"123456789","policyNumber":"12345"}' -H "Content-type:application/json" "${url}" -H "X-OnePass-API-Key: ${apikey}" -H "X-OnePass-ClientKey: ${clientkey}"
```

I run a check for eligible members and have a list of about 700 that I really don't want to copy & paste and then manually edit the data for each call.

My original code is in VBA Selenium which does not work with the API. It originally went to a website, used the data to fill in a form and submitted the form to grab the code. My shell scripting skills are still pretty basic or would python work better for this?

Comment: This might help: `jq  -c '.[]' file.json`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well use `json` and `requests` packages as follows :

```py
import json
import requests  

# Setup
API_KEY = ...
CLIENT_KEY = ...
URL = ...
HEADERS = {
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
    'X-OnePass-API-Key': API_KEY,
    'X-OnePass-ClientKey': CLIENT_KEY,
}

f = open('data.json', 'r')
  
# returns JSON object as 
# an array
data = json.load(f)
  
# Iterating through the json
for d in data:
    # Send HTTP request
    response = requests.post(URL, headers=headers, json=d)
    
    # Do whatever
    ...

f.close()
```

Comment: Apart from forgetting to close the file this is exactly the correct approach

Comment: As Cobra eluded to above, use `with open("data.json",'r') as f:` ... to ensure the file is closed after.